# Python学習環境ソフト、それぞれのメリットデメリットについて教えてください

Tags: python

PCスペック
・inteli-7　3740qm
・16GB、1TBHDD
・windows10home,64bit

目標
動作の軽い２ｄゲーム作り
（シューティング・ブロック崩し？等）

PyCharm
anaconda
visual　studio　chord
spider

開発ソフトはなにかいろいろあるようなのですが、今一つどれを導入すればいいかわかりません。

それぞれのメリット、デメリットなどを教えて下さると光栄です。よろしくおねがいします。

Comment: 同じような質問はせずに、前の質問を編集・修正してください。同じような質問をしても回答がばらけてしまうだけのため重複扱いで閉じられてしまいます。質問は「編集」をクリックすることでいつでも内容を修正できます。

Comment: 大変失礼しました。　ありがとうございます。